# Is it possible to access the buffer of a DatagramSocket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a DatagramSocket, and I know that socket.receive() has a buffer that stores packets that have been sent to the socket. I am trying to implement a reliable protocol using UDP, and it would be ideal if, after my window is full, I could unload the buffer all at once. If i did a simple loop, when the buffer is empty the socket.receive() would block my program, which I do not want.

Is there any way to access that buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a certain networks assignment due tonight...

There's no real way to unload all the packets at once. I would recommend instead setting the socket to timeout after a small period (smaller than the total timeout value the sender has), and looping through sending packets in your window and receiving acknowledgements.

Answer (score 0):

No, but there is `DatagramChannel` in non-blocking mode.

Answer (score -1):

`DatagramSocket` has no buffer. The network stack in your operating system has a buffer, but you cannot access it.

> I am trying to implement a reliable protocol using UDP

I would advice not to do that - you'll end up inventing TCP, but with bugs of your own.

Comment: Nobody said `DatagramSocket` has a buffer, actually, and you haven't answered the question.

Comment: The answer is no. The reason it is no is because there is no buffer.